# How to disable Fullcalendar preventations on events?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar v5.11.5 on my website. I added HTML inputs to events with `eventContent` function. When I try click to an input element it doesn't focus. `eventInteractive` is true but not working as expected. I wonder if there is an exact solution for this situation.

javascript code:

```js
let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialDate: '2024-02-26',
    locale: 'en',
    height: 'auto',
    eventColor: 'transparent',
    eventInteractive: true,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    eventContent: function(arg) {
        let event = arg.event.extendedProps;
        return {html: getEventHtml(event)};
    },
    eventSources: [
        {
            url: "https://www.example.com/source",
            method: "POST",
        },
    ],
});
calendar.render();
```

I tried `eventClick` function to focus input and it worked but not smooth as default input interaction.

```js
eventClick: function(info) {
    info.jsEvent.target.focus();
},
```

`getEventHtml()` returns:

```html
<div class="d-grid align-items-center justify-content-center text-center text-dark">
    <span class="inc-room-count btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-date="2024-02-26">+</span>
    <span>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm w-md-55px text-center numbers" value="1" data-date="2024-02-26">
    </span>
    <span class="dec-room-count btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-date="2024-02-26">-</span>
    <span class="mt-2 lowest-fill-level">0 / 1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `eventInteractive` makes the event element focusable. It says nothing about anything within it. And can we have a [mre] of the issue please? You've talked about the content of your event HTML but haven't actually shown us any HTML. WHat does `getEventHtml()` return, for example? See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson it doesn't really matter what returns `getEventHtml()` function but I added HTML to post.

Comment: It does, because we'd have to see what you're trying to put the focus on, and try to reproduce the scenario, otherwise we can't tell if there's a genuine issue or not. Again, see how to make a [mre]

Comment: Looks like an event can be focused with the tab key, but not focused with click: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/RwdXLwx

Comment: Per https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5963 you can hold down Ctrl while clicking and it works, but that's only a workaround, obviously

Comment: Yes, they all temporary solutions. Thanks anyway!